# Base64 encoding issue in Java

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, tobase64string

I have coded the following code to encode the byte[] **str**.

```
Byte[] str; 
Byte[] encoded=Base64.encodeToString(str);
```

But **Base64** word is not defined

I tried **base64.encode()** 
& **base64.getEncoder()**

I found a defined statement But I don't know how to use it:

```
byte[] encoded=Base64.encoder()
```

How to use it? Or how can I encode a string or byte[] with or without libraries.

Comment: Firstly, `Byte[]` and `byte[]` aren't the same types. You almost certainly want `byte[]`. Next, to use the `Base64` class in Android, you should import `android.util.Base64`.

Comment: Base64.encode**ToString** -> Don't try to push it into a byte array

Comment: Have you check the javadoc for `Base64.encoder()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `Base64` as `android.util.Base64`

`encodeToString` takes byte array and return String.

```
String encoded=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray);
```

Details about `Base64.encodeToString` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-)